# QT ComboBox ItemData from Database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, combobox

I have the following code which links a QT `QComboBox` to my sqlite database and it works great.
However in my database I have the Category and Item table linked with a foreign key.
So when I pull info from the `QComboBox` I need to get the `Category_ID` not the name which is listed in the box.
How would I go about setting the `QComboBox` ItemData to the `Category_ID` field with a model or better yet use the model to set the `QComboBox` ItemData as my Category Object?

Thanks,

```
void MainWindow::populatCat()
{
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    QString sql;
    sql = "select Category_Name From Category ORDER BY Category_Name ASC;";
    QSqlQuery* query = new QSqlQuery(db);
    query->prepare(sql);
    if(!query->exec()){
        qDebug () << "Query Erorr: " << query->lastError();
    }else{
        qDebug () << "Query Successful: " << query->lastQuery();
    }
    model->setQuery(*query);
    ui->cboCat->setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: Why not get Category_Name and Category_ID in the query.  Store both in something like std::map<QString, int> (Category_Name as the key).  Create a slot which takes a const QString& and is connected to the QComboBox's currentIndexChanged( const QString& ) signal.  Inside the slot, look up the key in the map, and get the Category_ID.

Comment: Actually that's probably not the best way.  However, I think you wills till have to do a look up of some sort, since the only thing it emits is text or it's index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll present an answer now. :)

```
QComboBox* myBox = new QComboBox();
connect( myBox, SIGNAL( indexChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( handleIndexChange( int ) ) );

void myObject::handleIndexChange( int /*index*/ ) {
    // We actually don't need the index
    QComboBox* box = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>( sender() );
    if ( box ) {
        QVariant data = box->currentData();  // do whatever w/ data... sounds like call toInt() in your case.
    }
}
```

The essence of all three of my approaches is that you have to do something extra to get data() which corresponds to the current item after a change.  It would be nice if it emitted a signal taking the underlying data as the argument, but that could get expensive.

Comment: Would it work to do a query based on the Category Name in the indexChanged that would populate the data or should I change the populateCat function to parse through the all the data and load the combobox at launch?

Comment: I'm not a DBA by any stretch, and I can't give you a good answer w/o more info, but a DB query in comparison to a lookup through already cached data is very slow (and expensive) -- usually, anyway.  Really depends on a lot of things: number of records and latency tolerance would be the main two.  You also need to think of how fast or slow your database can do the search.

Comment: K Thanks
I'll have to do some research and testing for the app I'm building to decide